# Trigger is not inserting values into the another table

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have written a `trigger` on **AFTER INSERT** like below

But it is not getting inserted into the table.

Comment: Mysql or Oracle?

Comment: @Aleksej: I am using `ORacle SQL developer` ..

Comment: @VVVV you might be, but that still doesn't answer the question - what is the database platform you're using? MySQL is a different RDBMS to Oracle.

Comment: @Boneist: OK, I am using Oracle.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the actual insert statement you're using? Also do you really want to insert data from *every row* in LOGSAPDEALSLIPFUNDREQINTGRTN into FR_CITYSTATE_COM_DET every time a 'does not exists' row is inserted? Or do you really only want data from the newly-inserted row to be copied?

Comment: @AlexPoole: updated the question

Comment: @AlexPoole: for now I want to insert when the column has the values as does not exist

Comment: @AlexPoole: After trying with `AFTER UPDATE` on trigger, I am updating column like this `update LOGSAPDEALSLIPFUNDREQINTGRTN set RESPONSESTRING = 'does not exists' where SAPID='I-TN-DMPI-ENB-0010' and LATITUDE = '12.15819';` but getting error as `ORA-04091: table APP_WFM.LOGSAPDEALSLIPFUNDREQINTGRTN is mutating, trigger/function may not see it`

Comment: You'll get that on insert too, because you're trying to insert *all rows from the table*, not just the single newly-inserted row's values. Your insert should be using :NEW values. When you execute that insert do you get no rows inserted, or do you get the same error?

Comment: @AlexPoole: can u help me with this logic, it would be great as I am not well in writing triggers and all

Comment: @AlexPoole: WHen I insert I get error as `SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here`

Comment: That ORA-00984 is nothing to do with the trigger; the last line of the insert has `null, null, O,  null, null, null` - is the `O` in that supposed to be the string `'O'`, or the number `0`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137553/discussion-between-vvvv-and-alex-poole).

Comment: can u come on chat.. now one row got inserted

Comment: Why have you removed your trigger code from your question??

Comment: due to some security reasons, I removed the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insert statement you added has one of the values as `O` (upper-case 'o' character); that either needs to be a string in single quotes (i.e. `'O'`) or the numeric digit zero (i.e. `0`), depending on the column data type. (If `logtime` is a date/timestamp field, the string literal `'15-04-14'` should also be an actual date - you're probably relying on implicit conversion, which is never a good idea).

However, your trigger will still get an ORA-04091 mutating table error, because you are basing your in-trigger insert on a query against the same table the trigger is against. You are currently trying to inset rows into `FR_CITYSTATE_COM_DET` for *every row* in `LOGSAPDEALSLIPFUNDREQINTGRTN`, which is unlikely to be what you meant.

You probably only want to insert a new row in `FR_CITYSTATE_COM_DET`  based on the row the trigger actually fired against, which means you should be using a `values()` clause rather than a select, and should be using the `:NEW` pseudorecord values in that, i.e.:

```
insert into fr_citystate_com_det (
  sapid,
  candidateid,
  city_name,
  city_code,
  r4g_state_name,
  r4g_state_code,
  statename,
  state_code,
  jc_id,
  area_code,
  system_date
)
values (
  :new.sapid,
  :new.candidateid,
  :new.city,
  :new.city,
  :new.state,
  :new.state,
  :new.state,
  :new.state,
  :new.jiocenter_id,
  :new.area_code,
  sysdate
);
```

Demo with invented table structures based on inserts:

```
create table logsapdealslipfundreqintgrtn(sapid varchar2(20), candidateid varchar2(20),
  companycode number, latitude number, longitude number, circle varchar2(20),
  state varchar2(20), city varchar2(20),address varchar2(12), rfsiteid varchar2(20),
  towertype varchar2(20), logtime varchar2(20), responsestring varchar2(20),
  logtype varchar2(20), towerht varchar2(20), transactionid varchar2(20),
  sapid_in_sap varchar2(20), nominal_sap_id varchar2(20), vendorcode varchar2(20),
  sitetype varchar2(20), jicenter_id varchar2(20), area_code varchar2(20),
  status varchar2(20), jiocenter_id varchar2(20));

create table fr_citystate_com_det(sapid varchar2(20), candidateid varchar2(20),
  city_name varchar2(20), city_code varchar2(20), r4g_state_name varchar2(20),
  r4g_state_code varchar2(20), statename varchar2(20), state_code varchar2(20),
  jc_id varchar2(20), area_code varchar2(20), system_date date);

create or replace trigger tr_fr_citystate_com_det after
  insert on logsapdealslipfundreqintgrtn
  for each row
begin
  if :new.responsestring like '%does not exists%'
  then
    insert into fr_citystate_com_det (
      sapid,
      candidateid,
      city_name,
      city_code,
      r4g_state_name,
      r4g_state_code,
      statename,
      state_code,
      jc_id,
      area_code,
      system_date
    )
    values (
      :new.sapid,
      :new.candidateid,
      :new.city,
      :new.city,
      :new.state,
      :new.state,
      :new.state,
      :new.state,
      :new.jiocenter_id,
      :new.area_code,
      sysdate
    );
  end if;
end;
/

Trigger TR_FR_CITYSTATE_COM_DET compiled

insert into LOGSAPDEALSLIPFUNDREQINTGRTN (SAPID,CANDIDATEID, companycode, latitude,
  longitude, circle, state, city,address, rfsiteid, towertype, logtime,
  responsestring, logtype, towerht, transactionid, sapid_in_sap, nominal_sap_id,
  vendorcode, sitetype, jiocenter_id, area_code, status)
values ('I-TN-DMPI-ENB-0010', 'C1', 5075, 12.15819,78.16203, 'TN', 'TN', 'DMPI',
  'Kovil Street', 'DMPI-RIL-0010', 'GBT', '15-04-14', 'does not exists', 'P1', 40,
  '130420215858576742', 'ITN-DMPI-ENB-0010', null, null, 'O', null, null, null);

1 row inserted.

select * from FR_CITYSTATE_COM_DET;

SAPID                CANDIDATEID          CITY_NAME            CITY_CODE            R4G_STATE_NAME       R4G_STATE_CODE       STATENAME            STATE_CODE           JC_ID                AREA_CODE            SYSTEM_DA
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------
I-TN-DMPI-ENB-0010   C1                   DMPI                 DMPI                 TN                   TN                   TN                   TN                                                             08-MAR-17
```

If you are getting duplicates and want to throw an exception if that is attempted, you could query the target table to check for an existing row before you insert:

```
...
for each row
declare
  l_count number;
begin
  if :new.responsestring like '%does not exists%'
  then
    select count(*) into l_count
    from fr_citystate_com_det
    where sapid = :new.sapid
    and candidateid = :new.candidateid
    and rownum = 1;

    if l_count > 0 then
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000, 'Cannot insert duplicate SAPID and CANDIDATEID');
    end if;

    insert into fr_citystate_com_det (
    ...
    )
    values (
    ...
    );
  end if;
end;
```

If there was a unique or primary key on `sapid, candidateid` then you would get an ORA-01001 exception anyway if you tried to insert a duplicate, but it seems you don't (from comments/chat). It seems like they **should** form a key though, if you want them to be unique. A unique key constraint is the right way to enforce uniqueness; don't replicate built-in functionality.

Apart form anything else, if two sessions inserting the same data simultaneously, they will each fire the trigger, each can't see the other's pending data so will get a count of zero, so both will insert the new record into `fr_citystate_com_det`. Using constraints avoids that problem.

If the columns aren't indexed at all then the count check may be slow too.

Alternatively, as I think I mentioned elsewhere, change whatever process does the insert and decides the 'does not exists' value is needed, and have that do *both* inserts, without hiding the logic in a trigger.

Comment: Hi, Alex in this code. I dont want user to insert duplicate records for the same `sapid` and `candidateid`. How to prevent that. ?

Comment: That comes back to how the 'does not exists' value is being put there in the first place; and also (maybe) if you've made this an after-update trigger as well. You can either do a query to count the number of rows that have the new sapid/candiateid and only insert if that has zero; or change the insert back to `insert ... select` but from dual and add a `where not exists` clause that checks the new value doesn't already exist.

Comment: OK. This seems to be something new  I guess. Should I go for new question or try it updating here only ?. IF possible pls come on chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137553/discussion-between-vvvv-and-alex-poole

Comment: @VVVV - yes, probably should have been a new question, though maybe too broad and there are lots of examples of how to avoid duplicates. I've added examples to this answer already though.

Comment: I have two if conditions here now, you can see my updated trigger on chat. let me know is that fine